# Adding New ADODB.Recordset instantly causes Crash

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm fairly new to Access, but I have never had anything like this happen to me.

I have an Access DB that I am creating, and I have been using recordsets to grab values for variables. I have several of these running in my code without any problems.

However, now whenever I add this line `Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset` Access stops responding. I've tried saving it to a new location, but it still errors out as soon as I enter in a new recordset. Waiting it out doesn't seem to work either.

Now I have no idea what to do. Any help that can be provided would be immensely appreciated. This is driving me insane.

EDIT IN:
Creating a new recordset in this method `Dim rs2 AS ADODB.Recordset` causes a crash as well.

EDIT 2: It appears to specific to just this class. Is it impossible to use both ADODB and a DAO in the same class? I just added a DAO recordset to my project. Perhaps that's causing the problem. Commenting out the DAO recordset creation doesn't stop Access from crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another thing to try is your idea of commenting out the DAO code, but also unchecking the reference to the DAO library.  I'm unaware of any conflicts between the two, but that's how you'd verify it.

Comment: Alright, now we're getting somewhere. It seems that block commenting out the DAO code allows me to SET ADODB again. Anyone have any definitive answers as why this might happen. I guess I'll have to look into recoding that section with ADODB.

Comment: Nothing definitive, but if any of your types (e.g. RecordSet) appear in code without an explicit appropriate ADODB or DAO prefix, there is a very good chance you ended up passing the wrong type of RecordSet to a function at some point.  I would have thought that would be caught by a VBA compiler or run-time error, though, before out-and-out crashing Access...